# How to convert from UTC time to local time zone of the browser?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I got this time zone from backend code:

```
2018-05-28T00:00:00Z
```

How to convert this to local time zone?

Answer (score 2):

You just construct a `Date` object.

```
let d = new Date("2018-05-28T00:00:00Z");
console.log(d.toString());
```

The date/time will be converted to the browser's current locale and timezone.

You can convert it back to ISO format like this.

```
console.log(d.toISOString());
```